# replace div with php content

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have a div . when i click on any sub-element list-item, i am posting the item no. to a php file which displays a some details corresponding to that list item. but there are two problems :

first, i want to replace the div  with the content of the php file..
second, i am getting an error while processing the php file :

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

the div looks like:

```
<div id="list">
            <?php

            $query = "SELECT * from workflow WHERE name = '$username' ORDER BY msg_id DESC";
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die("ERROR: $query.".mysql_error());

                while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
                    echo "<div class=list-item-wrap>";
                    echo "<a href='#'><input class=msgid type=hidden value=".$row->msg_id."><div class=list-item>";
                    echo "<b><h1>".$row->subject."</h1></b>".substr($row->message, 0, 200)."...<br><b>".$row->sender."</b>";
                    echo "</div></a></div>";
                }
            ?>
                <br>
            </div>


    </div>
```

the php file looks like:

```
<?php
include 'header.php';

$msg_id = $_POST['msg_id'];
//$msg_id = 1;

$query = "SELECT * from workflow WHERE msg_id = $msg_id";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
        //echo $row->username;

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
        echo "<div id=display-wrap>";
        echo "<h1>".$row->sender."</h1><br>";
        echo "<h2>".$row->subject."</h2>";
        echo "<h3>".$row->datetime."</h3><br>";
        echo "<h3>".$row->message."</h3><br>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: "Hey look my msg_id is `Robert';DROP TABLE workflow; --` OH GOD WHERE DID MY DATABASE GO" -- Bobby Tables

Comment: Why don't you start by putting `echo $query;` after `$query = ...` in your code. Then, post the finished query.

Comment: The $username is empty --> to use near '' at line 1

Comment: ***@CanSpice**: really nice shot! Hope his db-user hasn't permission to DROP anything. Hahaha!

Comment: @Fernando: possibly, but the variable's enclosed in quotes within the query, so if the var's blank, the query'd still be `... name=''` which is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

OK, i was looking around and found this question still unanswered after 2 months.  Here goes.

First off: your query in the second file looks OK, **if (and *only* if) `$_POST['msg_id']` is a number**.  But since you're not doing any quoting or escaping or validation on the value here, you can't guarantee that.  Set `$msg_id` like

```
$msg_id = intval($_POST['msg_id']);
```

to take care of that problem if `msg_id` should be an int.  Anything that's not a number will become zero, allowing you to easily check for unset or invalid values if you care.  (This assumes your IDs will never legitimately be zero, which is a valid assumption in a table with an `auto_increment` ID field.)  If `msg_id` is anything besides numbers, you'll need to change the query to look like

```
$msg_id_sql = mysql_real_escape_string($msg_id);
$query = "SELECT * from workflow WHERE msg_id = '$msg_id_sql'";
```

Secondly: **Check to make sure `$username` has a value, and that the HTML that's generated by the first script is correct.**  Also, you should escape it (using `mysql_real_escape_string`, as above) before using it in your query, especially if it came from the user.  Since you didn't really post anything about that here, it's something you'll need to do yourself.  What you're trying to do looks pretty odd, really...hidden fields aren't very useful unless you're submitting the form they're in (which would reload the page, defeating the purpose of all the ajax stuff).

Thirdly: **To do the actual retrieval and replacement, i'd recommend jQuery.**  `innerHTML` is common, but not standard.  Some browsers support it, some don't...and jQuery hides those differences (as well as hiding the complexity of handling async form posts and such).  Sample jQuery code (which may or may not need minor changes; i don't have test stuff handy):

```
$.post('second_page.php',
    { msg_id: some_msg_id_to_retrieve },
    function(data) { $('#the_results_div_id').html(data); }
);
```

I don't intend to go into how to do it in vanilla JS.  (I could if absolutely necessary, but eh -- it's like 4-5 times as much code, at least.)  If you really want to do it without jQuery, google for `XMLHttpRequest` (for the retrieval part) and `innerHTML` (to replace the div's contents with your own stuff).

Fourth:  `mysql_query` and friends are way, WAY past their prime, and should be dragged out and shot.  (Whoever taught you to use them probably ought to be as well, considering he's become part of the problem.  :P)  **Google for `PDO` (PHP Data Objects) and/or `mysqli`**; both provide a feature known as "prepared statements" which allows you to separate your query and your data.  That separation provides a number of benefits -- one being that you can build and run a query safely without having to worry much about what your data looks like.  (As long as you're not one of those idjits that relies on magic quotes.  If you do, frankly, you're pretty well screwed.  Magic quotes do the wrong thing when you least expect it, making SQL injection pretty much unavoidable.)

Anyway, i prefer PDO, but either is better than the `mysql` functions.

Answer (score -3):

Hmm, try cleaning up the SQL

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `workflow` WHERE `name` = '$username' ORDER BY `msg_id` DESC";
```

It could also be the content you are putting in the variables $username.

As far as updating the div's content, AJAX is your easiest solution in my opinion.

Comment: -1 for perpetuating the "let's use SQL without using placeholders" problem.

Comment: That said, how does this even remotely answer the question or solve the problem?

Comment: Woah woah woah, lets not get into details here. He/She simply asked why its causing an error. The question doesn't ask "What is the proper way to execute SQL?"

Comment: Randomly littering backticks in a query isn't the solution. They're only necessary if you've used a reserved word for something other than its usual purpose. None of his field names are reserved words, so the backticks are useless.

Comment: Someone who's doing something wrong usually doesn't know they are.  If they did, they'd fix it.  That's why when someone asks (or answers!) a question, and it's clear they're doing stuff wrong, it *should* be pointed out.  Otherwise, the madness continues.

Answer (score -4):

In your query try to change

```
$query = "SELECT * from workflow WHERE name = '$username' ORDER BY msg_id DESC";
```

to

```
$query = "SELECT * from workflow WHERE name = '".$username."' ORDER BY msg_id DESC";
```

Same goes with the msg id also.

Comment: the error says that there is error in syntax and the variable should be concatenated with the string. so i suggest to use '".$username."' and '".$msg_id."' in the respective DIV query and the query in the php file.

Comment: `$txt = "hello $othervar hello";` and `$txt = "hello " . $othervar . " hello";` are absolutely identical in functionality.